# Plotted Graph vs Scattered Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data which I am trying to plot. However when I call plot function, I get a weird line. How can I get rid of this thing and why does it occur ?[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us help you, check out [ask] and [example] and revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

The plot function draws lines between points. If there is a "weird" line, then it means you are providing two consecutive points  that form that line